Fantasy manhwa with demon king army and an overpowered white haired main character
The main character is the strongest in the demon king army among the comanders. He is secretly a human and is sick or something and wants to leave the demon army. He actually is very weak, but has like a second persona that is the overpowered one. At the start of the manhwa the hero attacks the demon king castle and he kills the hero.
I only read first few chapters and don't remember much but I swear this thing exist. I read it on a website called "manganelo". The manhwa is fully coloured.

Definitely full color? There's a black&white manga with the basic premise of "secretly a human in the demon lord's army". I think he's genuinely overpowered and wouldn't kill the hero, so not a perfect match regardless.

Nvm I found it. Its called I'm not that kind of talent.

This is I'm Not That Kind of Talent.

A talented individual who is respected by many and welcomed anywhere? Not at all! A bloodthirsty battle fanatic who knows no defeat? Couldn’t be further from the truth! In reality, Deon Hardt is a sickly human who coughs up blood from receiving the tiniest bit of stress and gets sunburns from standing in the sun for ten minutes. But due to an unfortunate misunderstanding, he becomes “Demon Arut,” the notorious 0th corps commander of the demon army and the demon king’s joker. Caught in a war between humans and demonkind, Deon must find a way to survive!

The synopsis covers most of the question - the protagonist is a weak human, misunderstood to be extremely strong. The first chapter has him kill the hero that was attacking the demon lord, but doesn't cover how he does this despite being weak.
There's no mention of a second persona within the first two chapters, just huge misunderstandings and people mistaking him being scared as being filled with bloodlust, etc.
